# The right way to at the same time talk of a modified adjective and its unmodified form?

Tags: punctuation, modifiers

> We don't know how **pervasive** that is.

and

> We don't know how **increasingly pervasive** that is.

How to combine the above two sentences into one sentence? A popular way is to use parentheses, as:

> We don't know how **(increasingly) pervasive** that is.

How acceptable is that way and is there any other way?

Answer (score 4):

*How increasingly pervasive...?* is an awkward construction which appears to be asking two questions, not just one:

- It is pervasive ... ***How*** pervasive is it?
- Its pervasiveness is increasing ... ***How rapidly*** is its pervasiveness increasing?

There's no graceful way of posing both questions in a single clause—you need two. But you can include them both in a single sentence:

> We don't know how pervasive it is, or how rapidly its pervasiveness is increasing.

Comment: What's wrong with the form with parentheses?

Comment: @Sasan It leaves the reader uncertain what it is you don't know. I'm a pretty sophisticated reader, but I don't know whether in fact you intend to express your ignorance of both those matters or only one--and if only one, which. Conciseness is desirable, but secondary; the writer's primary job is to make the utterance as ***clear*** as possible.

Comment: Arguably your version is "loaded", in that it tacitly assumes the pervasiveness is definitely increasing. If that assumption is unjustifiable, it could be avoided with could be avoided with *or **whether and how rapidly** its pervasiveness is increasing.* Just don't ask me whether that should be *whether **or** how rapidly*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good point. I assumed from OP's placing *increasingly* within the scope of the interrogative that OP made that assumption explicity--which only reinforces the point in my previous comment that *How (increasingly) pervasive* is ambiguous.

Comment: Imho, "accidentally on purpose" *persuasive* writing is *pervasive* (also either or both of *invidious* and *insidious*, which I always get mixed up).

Comment: @FumbleFingers What if I have assumed, and already pointed, that "it is pervasive" and "its pervasiveness is increasing". Can I then say "we don't know how (increasingly) pervasive it is?

Comment: @Sasan Let's say no. Will you then ask someone else?

Comment: @Sasan: Then as StoneyB says, you'd be using "an **awkward** construction". Personally, if I read that I doubt I'd bother expending the mental effort to figure out *exactly* what the writer might or might not have meant, but it's your stylistic choice to make.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What is your point exactly?

Comment: You've been given a good answer. You don't seem to like it. You even invite others over here from different threads, probably trying to get a second opinion. These agree with the first. Are you claiming to be as skilled in these matters as StoneyB and FumbleFingers?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I didn't force you to answer. Do you have problem with me inviting you to answer?

Comment: @Sasan When StoneyB gives an answer with which FF and I agree and nobody seems to disagree, isn't it time just to thank StoneyB and accept? / The question is now on hold as being POB, but FF and I concur with Stoney B that the bracketed version is not good (though it is not ungrammatical) and that his (or FF's if that is required) rewrite is better.